# Collateralized / uncollateralized swap

Tags: derivatives, swaps, cva, irs, collateral

Is a fully collateralized interest rate swap considered free of counterparty credit risk? Or close to risk free? Therefore discounted by the rate that best proxies the risk-free rate (which is the OIS-rate)? And then you have the fair value, no more adjustments?

For a swap that is not collateralized, or not fully collateralized, the practice is to derive the risk-free value by OIS-discounting, and then perform any applicable value adjustments (CVA, DVA, FVA)?

Or is practice divided on uncollateralized swaps? Do some people adjust for credit risk directly, by using a discount rate other than OIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Discount

Yes, usually, people discount using the risk free rate, and then adjust for the counterparty credit risk (CVA), funding cost (FVA), and so on.

#### 2. Collateral

**The Margin period of risk:**

In the case of default, the counterparty will usually stop posting collateral for a given period of time before being closed-out. This period is called the margin period of risk: $MPOR$.

As a result, for credit exposures computation, the collateral used is computed based on market values that are lagged by $MPOR$: $$Collateral(t, \omega) = f(MtM(t - MPOR, \omega))$$

**CCR for collateralized trades**

The above, combined with the fact that collateral agreements are not perfect (thresholds, minimum transfer amounts, etc.), implies that a swap that is subject to *variation margin* can still have some counterparty credit risk.

However, if the swap is subject both to *initial margin* and *variation margin* then nothing will be left in terms of counterparty credit risk.

In this case the CCR is essentially replaced by other costs (e.g. the initial margin gives rises to a new adjustment called the MVA to account for funding costs of this IM).

Comment: I just want to add that the discounting is done at OIS (Fed Funds) because in a perfect csa with cash being posted, it actually specifies interest to be paid on the variation margin at Fed Funds.

Comment: Usually, the discount is done at OIS, assuming a perfect CSA. Any divergence of the CSA from this perfect case (e.g. cheapest to deliver, etc.) will give rise to yet another adjustment: the ColVA.

Comment: @profesarrmariorty, thanks for the beer :) I'd take an "accept" instead for now if this answers your question to help other people having the same question find this answer quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

The pre-crisis concept of a risk-free rate was either government securities or LIBOR-based swap rates. As LIBOR is unsecured bank borrowing-lending rate, this was clearly an approximation too far.

Counterparty credit adjustments for a bank, and post-crisis discounting: The value is derived by discounting at the overnight (OIS) rate, and then apply xVA adjustments, including to margin (@byouness).

You may find that non-bank institutions, especially those that are permitted to measure credit risk and supply capital using a framework that diverges from BCBS i.e. SII, use a discount rate other than LIBOR or OIS.